# Do I have to set the attribute as a primary key again?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table where there is a ID attribute, and this attribute is a primary key, If I want to set the ID as auto_increment, by using the modify column command, do I have to set the ID atribbute as primary key again?

Should I use this code?

```
  alter table testing modify column ID int primary key auto_increment;
```

or this one?

```
 alter table testing modify column ID int auto_increment;
```

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to use the long form.

Comment: the point is that I want to know it the column will be still a primary key after I use the second example @TheImpaler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short form is OK: modifying the column to `auto_increment` does not drop the primary key constraint.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/738pUWEnrLdDdWqsnzMLGd/0)** (tested in MySQL 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, and 8.0):

```
create table testing (ID int primary key);
alter table testing modify column ID int auto_increment;
insert into testing values(1);
insert into testing values(1);
```

> Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'